# Outsource the generated Swing code

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, windowbuilder

Is there any way to outsource the generated Java source code from the actual class (the frame or panel class) into an XML file (for example)?

I do not like this messy Swing code in my GUI objects; it makes my class huge and unreadable.

I know that the GUI Builder which is implemented into the IntelliJ IDEA can do that (see http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/gui_builder.html).

Comment: And which GUI designer do you use under Eclipse?

Comment: I use WindowBuilder. I guess that's the standard GUI builder?!

Comment: There are more than just that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GUI Builder (from Google, formerly Instantiations) always generate Java code. That is actually the primary idea of the designer :-)

There are many things you can do using Java as the implementation language that cannot be done with XML or other static specification languages.

*EDIT:* You can also look at [XWT - XML Windowing Toolkit](http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/XWT) - though I don't whether it works under Eclipse 3 or "just" Eclipse 4...

Comment: Thats true, but the IntelliJ IDE for example, generates a *.form file where all the layout things are stored in. The actual implementation of the frame (or panel) only contains the necessary variables and event handlers. So I thought that there could maybe a way that there is such a possibility for Eclipse.